# How to draw a curved banner in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to create a curved banner like this in GIMP. I've tried the Paths Tool, but I couldn't get it exact.
Is there another way, or was I using the Paths Tool incorrectly?

[image: Curved banner]

Comment: You should probably consider inkscape for this

Comment: This isn't a job for a raster image editor like GIMP. Much better, and much easier to use a vector image editor such as Inkscape (free and Open Source), or Adobe Illustrator (not free).

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't necessarily disagree.. but Photoshop has a warp feature which would work fine.. I don't know if Gimp has a comparable feature.

Comment: @Scott - it does, but not as easy to use or control. Much easlier to just do this in Inkscape, convert everything to paths, group, and just apply a Bend live path effect.

Comment: Yeah I again agree (although I'd use Illustrator) `:)` it's just sometimes about the tools you have (or know) than what may be better utilized. I've realized lately that those of us that know a wide range of tools sometimes forget that *many* people, especially more hobbyists,  only use one tool.. and most often only a raster tool.

Comment: @Scott this is such a beginner level task that learning to do this in inkscape has a better investment value for ones time. Sure it takes 0-20 mintes more of ones time but one has learned a skill for life that will help in future.

Comment: I don't disagree @joojaa `:)` But "get it done" is quite different than "learn how to do it correctly" `:)` Sure everyone *should* learn the proper way.. but If I'm a cashier at a local grocery store and have no need to boost my skills as a designer, and just need a curved banner for a birthday card I'm making for my grandma... do I *really* need to learn Inkscape? `:)` It's all relative.

Comment: Point being.. there's a difference between building professional quality furniture you intend to sell... and putting together that particle board nightstand you bought from Ikea.

Comment: @Scott yes but you should learn when its trivial

Comment: @joojaa .. but **only** if that learning is something you'll utilize in the future. For many, it may not be. `:)` I don't need to learn how to create dovetail joint to put together an Ikea item, even though a dovetail joint would be much more reliable. Basically... if I knew how to use Gimp I'd answer this. There's no reason to *not* answer merely because a better method, using other software, may exist. Not *everyone* is a professional seeking to further their professional skills.

Comment: @Scott sure. Im inclined to think that somebody who is not 90 years old probably will. Anyway this is the golden opportunity to do this nearly for free.

Comment: There is a script to this in Gimp, see [this](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-ofn-text-along-path)

Comment: The small prints in questioner's example are not worth of imitating. They are not properly curved, the words are straight, but tilted one by one a little randomly.  That makes the whole thing look unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it done using the Paths Tool in GIMP:

[image: Successful]

Comment: Yeah, but what about the text curved text?  That's only a shape, not a banner yet.